# prolog, comparing two predicates

Tags: prolog, predicate

I have this proLog environtment (cooking stuff):

```
first("ajo-blanco").
first("brandada-de-bacalao").

second("empanadilla-de-jamon-y-soja").
second("pollo-al-ajillo").

category("ajo-blanco", aperitivos_tapas).
category("brandada-de-bacalao", aperitivos_tapas).
category("empanadilla-de-jamon-y-soja", aperitivos_tapas).
category("pollo-al-ajillo", carnes_y_aves).

same_category(Primero, Segundo) :-
    category(Primero, Type) = category(Segundo, Type).

menu_simple(Primero, Segundo) :-
    first(Primero),
    second(Segundo),
    same_category(Primero, Segundo).
```

I define 4 plates, 2 first plates and 2 second plates. A menu_simple object is a menu that has 2 plates: 1 first and 1 second and this two plates are not from the same category, so the 2 correct combinations for the menu_simple predicate are:

> "ajo-blanco" + "pollo-al-ajillo", "brandada-de-bacalao" +
>   "pollo-al-ajillo"

My problem is that the following predicate:

> same_category(Primero, Segundo)

always returns false when I try it.

> same_category("pollo-en-salsa", "ajo-blanco").

returns false (this is correct, they dont have the same category)

> same_category("ajo-blanco", "empanadilla-de-jamon-y-soja").

returns f alse too (this is wrong, they dont have the same category)

I am sure that I'm missing something since im new into prolog. Any help would be apreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not a Prolog expert but... if you write

```
same_category(Primero, Segundo) :-
  category(Primero, Type) = category(Segundo, Type).
```

you ask that `category(Primero, Type)` and `category(Segundo, Type)` are equal; and this is true only when `Primero = Segundo`.

But `Primero` is a first, `Segundo` is a second and there is no intersection between firsts and seconds.

If you want to check that `Primero` and `Segundo` are in the same category, you should check that the type of `Primero` is the same type of `Segundo`, that is

```
same_category(Primero, Segundo) :-
    category(Primero, TypeP),
    category(Segundo, TypeS),
    TypeP = TypeS.
```

that is equivalent to

```
same_category(Primero, Segundo) :-
    category(Primero, Type),
    category(Segundo, Type).
```

Another observation: if you want that "this two plates are not from the same category", your actual `menu_simple/2` is wrong because select a `Primero` and a `Segundo` in the same category.